# Creating a batch files for visaul studio command

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, wcf, svcutil.exe

Hi i have 2 commands need to execute in visual studio command prompt at one time using batch file.

C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Client\InterviewManagementServiceClient>svcutil http://localhost:19021/InterviewManagementService/InterviewManagementService.svc /l:C# /out:Reference.cs  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /t:code /n:*,iWatch.InterviewManagementService

C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient>svcutil http://localhost:19012/EfileService/EfileService.svc /l:C# /out:Reference.cs  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /t:code /n:*,iWatch.EfileService

i want to create a one batch file(.bat file) which will execute these two commands in visual studio command prompt.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Clarifying what you have problem with (like "how to create text file and save it with .bat exception") may help, but also may finally push this question to "off-topic, should be on SU" or something like this. Definitely not very clear in current state so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can create a batch(.bat) file for executing the multiple commands in visual studio command prompt explained below.

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

the above command will call the visual studio command prompt and then we have to wrote our multiple commands then it will be executed and save this file in .bat file.