# Executing multiple command in visual studio command prompt using bat file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, svcutil.exe

Hi i have multiple command need to execute in visual studio command prompt.

```
C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Client\mycalenderserviceclient
svcutil http://localhost:1544/mycalenderservice/mycalenderservice.svc /l:C# /out:Reference.cs /config:app.config  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /t:code /n:*,iWatch.mycalenderservice/r:"C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Services\DataModel\obj\Debug\DataModel.dll
C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Client\mydatecontrolsserviceclient
svcutil http://localhost:7777/mydatecontrolsservice/mydatecontrolsservice.svc /l:C# /out:Reference.cs /config:app.config  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /t:code /n:*,iWatch.mydatecontrolsservice /r:"C:\iwatch\trunk\CPCE Services\DataModel\obj\Debug\DataModel.dll
```

I want to execute these 4 commands one time in visual studio command prompt using batch file(.bat).

Comment: Is this in an existing file, or are you trying to create the batch file and then execute it all from within the code? If the former, look into the [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If the latter, look into writing text to a file (`File.Create(string)` and `StreamWriter.Write(string)`), then use the aforementioned `Process.Start(string)`.

Comment: Please do not post your question multiple times (http://stackoverflow.com/q/32082212/745969).  If the question is not getting attention, try editing it to make it clearer what you are asking.